# store form data into database using ajax json php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to store form data in database but my code is reflecting anything.
Here is my code

**add.php**

```
<form name='reg' >
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student information:-</legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label> FirstName:  </label><input type="text" id="name"  name="name" required>
            <span id='error' style="display:none;color:red;"> Only alphabets </span>
        </li>  

        <li>
            <label> LastName: </label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"  required>
            <span id='error1' style="display:none;color:red;"> Only alphabets </span>

        </li> 
        <li>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        </li>

        <label>
            Gender:  </label> 
        <input type="radio" id='gender' name="gender" value="male" required> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id='gender' value="female" required> Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id='gender' value="other" required> Other

        <li>
            <label>
                Email:    </label>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email"  required>
            <span id='error2' style="display:none;color:red;"> Invalid email </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label> Mobile:</label>
            <input id="mobile" type="text" maxlength="10" name="mobile"  required >
            <span id='error3' style="display:none;color:red;"> only digits </span>
        </li>  
        <li>
            address: <textarea name="address" id="address" type="text" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></textarea>

        </li>   

    </ul>
    <p><a href="" class="btn btn-info"  id="btnBooking">Register</a></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and javascript file is as

**serve.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnBooking").on("click", function (e) {

        // as you have used hyperlink(a tag), this prevent to redirect to another/same page
        e.preventDefault();

        // get values from textboxs  
        var name = $('#name').val();
        // alert('name');
        var lname = $('#lname').val();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var gender = $('#gender').val();
        var mail = $('#email').val();
        var mobNum = $('#mobile').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/project_cloud/fun.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {type: "add", Name: name, Lname: lname, User: username, Pass: password, Gen: gender, Email: mail, Mob_Num: mobNum, Addr: address},
            //type: should be same in server code, otherwise code will not run
            ContentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })
    });
});
```

and another php file which stores the result in database

**fun.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("ocean");

if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $res = [];

    if ($_GET['type'] == "add") {
        $name = $_GET ['Name'];
        $lname = $_GET['Lname'];
        $userN = $_GET['User'];
        $passW = $_GET['Pass'];
        $gen = $_GET['Gen'];
        $mail = $_GET ['Email'];
        $mobile = $_GET ['Mob_Num'];
        $address = $_GET['Addr'];
        $query1 = "insert into oops(username, password, firstname, lastname, gender, email, mobile, address) values('$userN','$passW','$name','$lname','$gen','$mail','$mobile','$address')";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

        if ($result1) {
            $res["flag"] = true;
            $res["message"] = "Data Inserted Successfully";
        } else {
            $res["flag"] = false;
            $res["message"] = "Oppes Errors";
        }
    }
} else {
    $res["flag"] = false;
    $res["message"] = "Invalid format";
}

echo json_encode($res, $result1);
?>
```

When I write my **`serve.js`** file code in **`add.php`** file it gives me result as stored in database .But when I tried to separate it js file it shows nothing. What wrong in it or I missing something.

Comment: In your ajax request you POST data but in your PHP file (fun.php) you try to retrieve GET data ($_GET).

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
type:"post",
```

in your AJAX request, but server side handle $_GET parameters:

```
$lname = $_GET['Lname'];
```

Change `$_GET` to `$_POST` and you'll see your values.

But all your code is terrible. You can't publish this in Internet. You have bad JavaScript and many issues serverside, include MySQL Injection. Need to rewrite all of this with prepared statements and JS to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnBooking").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).parents('form').serializeArray();
        data.type = 'add'
        $.post('/project_cloud/fun.php',data)
        .done(function(response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
        .fail(function(err){
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        })
    });
})
```